# Measure addon CPU in Firefox over time

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

There is a question to find out what amount of CPU is used in a particular Tab or Addon in Firefox. Now in Firefox 50 beta you can see this measurement every 10 seconds in about:performance

However I would like to know if Profiler can capture this performance over time and how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [gecko profiler addon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) to do... well.. profiling. Note that using it on 64bit windows builds of firefox can currently lead to some instability.